# UK gun licenses prior to Firearms Amendment Act 1988

Tags: licensing, legal-history, firearms

[The Firearms (Amendment) Act 1988](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firearms_(Amendment)_Act_1988) came into force as a response to the [Hungerford massacre of 1987](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungerford_massacre).

The perpetrator had legally owned some firearms, including a semi-automatic assault rifle.

Before the amendment came into force, what were the requirements for a UK citizen to be issued a license to possess firearms such as semi-automatic military rifles? Was there any connection to the applicants profession or could, in theory, anyone deemed sane by the authorities receive such a license?